# Linux Process Monitoring Using Statsd and Graphite

Tags: linux, centos, monitoring, graphite, statsd

I would like to monitor linux processes (log cpu and ram usage statistics and display them graphically over a period of time) using statsd and graphite. I have configured statsd and graphite to run as services.

How can I send linux resource usage statistics (namely CPU and RAM) to statsd so that they can be graphically viewed from the graphite web UI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use collectd (collectd.org) to get our OS-level metrics into Graphite. We don't go through stated, but collectd has its own summarizing functionality.

Comment: How do you configure collectd to get statistics for selected linux processes given their pid's

Comment: This can be done through Processes plugin which captures the statistics through process names (not pid's)